# Lack of continuity in promotion rules of C++, any flag to avoid it?

Tags: c++

The code bellow shows the promotion of a short to an int when resolving the overload of the function `fold`.
The problem is that if we change `short int` with `int` and `int` with `long` the code doesn't compiles any more due to ambiguous overload.
Is there any compiler flag ( in any compiler ) in order to avoid that lack of continuity in promotion rules ?

```
#include <iostream>

short int fold(short int a, short int b){return a+b;}   
int fold(int a, int b){return a+b;}

int main(int argc, char **argv){       
std::cout<<fold((short)32767,(short)1)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<fold(32767,(short)1)<<std::endl;   return 0;  
}
```

In order to be more clear the code could also be written as:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef short int I1; typedef int I2;

//typedef int I1; typedef long I2;

I1 fold(I1 a, I1 b){return a+b;}
I2 fold(I2 a, I2 b){return a+b;}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    std::cout<<fold((I1)32767,(I1)1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<fold((I2)32767,(I1)1)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Until someone writes such a compiler, no.

Comment: to disambiguate the call (in the general case) even more complex rules would be required.

Comment: For the case of the `long int`, have you tried adding a literal? e.g: `123L`

Comment: doesn't makes difference

Comment: You should come up with the rule for the flag first. If you cannot define a concrete rule to when a warning should be raised, then there can be no flag